# Laravel 5 - creating two tables during registration

Tags: authentication, database-design, laravel-5

In my database design, I have two tables, `People` & `Auth`. The Auth table holds authentication information and the person_id while the People table holds all other information (name, address, etc). There is a one-to-one relationship between the tables as seen in the models below.

> The reason I have separated the data into two tables is because in my
>   application, I will have many people who do not have authentication
>   capabilities (customers to the user).

**App/Auth.php**

```
   class Auth extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
    {
        use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

        public function person() {
            $this->belongsTo('Person');
        }
    }
```

**App/Person.php**

```
class Person extends Model
{
    public function auth() {
        $this->hasOne('Auth');
    }
}
```

In my AuthController::create() method, I am attempting to populate both models with the user supplied information like this:

```
protected function create(Request $request)
    {
        $person = \App\Person::create($request->all());

        $auth = new \App\Auth;
        $auth->fill($request->all());
        $auth->person_id = $person->id;
        $auth->save();

        return $person;
    }
```

In my application, I would like to authorize a user and pass a $user object as the authenticated person to subsequent routes. Am I doing this correctly? Is this the best way? There's cookies and bonus points if you can also explain how to retrieve the $user object after authentication...Auth table data is not needed in the $user object.

***EDIT***

I have changed my `config/Auth.php` file to reflect the changes as noted in the answers below (thx @user3702268). However, I have now found an error with my controller. In the AuthController::create() method, I am returning my App/Person object and this throws an `ErrorException` seeing as how App/Person does not implement the Authorizable trait. I do not want my App/Person object to be authorizable, but it is the object that I want returned as the authenticated $user in my views. How? Shall I simply override the `postRegister` method or is there a more Laravel way?

***EDIT 2***

I'm now returning the $auth object which uses the authorizable trait. In my views/controllers I'm trying to access the Person using `Auth::user()->person` but getting `Class 'Person' not found` errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace the App\User Class in config/auth.php line 31 the class that contains the username and password:

```
'model' => App\User::class,
```

to

```
'model' => App\Auth::class,
```

Be sure to encrypt the password before saving by using the bcrypt($request->get('password')) helper or Hash::make($request->get('password')). Then you can authenticate by calling:

```
Auth::attempt([$request->get('username'), $request->get('password')]);
```

You can retrieve the authenticated user using this:

```
Auth::user()
```

Comment: I noticed in `config/Auth.php` that I should also change `'table'=>'auth'` as my table name is different also. The tables are being populated properly and I'm returning my Person object! +1

Since I changed my table to auth and my model to Auth...will that cause conflicts with the Auth facade?

Comment: Nope, your Auth class should be in another namespace, default is putting it in the App\Auth namespace. If you want to use both classes, you should Alias one or Both e.g.    
    use App\Auth as AuthModel use Auth <---- Auth facade

Comment: You should return your Auth class and you can access the Person class in your views using the relationship:

    Auth::user()->person

Comment: I've tried that and am now getting the error `Class 'Person' not found`. I believe it is because App/Auth belongsTo App/Person and not the other way around?

Comment: Check if the person_id is saved in the Auth table

Comment: The database is populated correctly...there is a person_id in auth table and a matching record in the people table. I've also set a foreign key on people_id in the auth table. I also specifically set the table namees in my models, in case the plural stuff didn't work right...still Class not found